# Trying to access the value of a text field in PHP before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to access text entered by user in a text field even before submitting the form. For this, I am thinking to adding a click event on 'Submit' button to access the value of text field using Jquery. But, I am not sure how to assign it back to a PHP variable.

Can someone help?

```
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" name="inputs1" class="inputs1" placeholder="Enter the name" required>
        <input type="button" class="submit-btn" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php $variable = ? //value of input field name ?>
```

Comment: Some code perhaps?

Comment: Please just assume a text field along with a submit button. You are free to use any class name or ids etc.

Comment: No thanks. My assumptions are never close to reality

Comment: I just a added a bit code. You may want to check it out.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? PHP is a server-side language and is executed and finishes before the data is sent to the browser. If you can explain better what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can use jquery to change the value of the input in the form, as well as capturing the form submission to manipulate the contents before it goes back to the server (where your php lives). When you get back to the server, you can use a GET to get the variable from the querystring and assign it's value to any php variable you want.

Comment: In my comment I mentioned the GET because in your form code, you're not showing a form post method.

Answer (score 1):

php is a server-side scripting language. so you cant really assign a value to php variable until a request is sent for the server to process i.e. form is submitted

Comment: There should be a way to assign a value to PHP variable via jquery. Isn't there any?

Comment: i'm afraid doing that on client side is not possible

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you can't until you submit the form. Instead you can do this with Javascript.